# Testing C code by compiling with -s switch?

Tags: c, linux, compilation

I want to test my code (I know my code is still incomplete -- yes I am planning to complete it before I compile it) to see if it gives the correct assembly code by compiling with -s switch, how do I do this?
    
I am not very familiar with compiling. All I did so far was save my file. Now I need to compile it to be able to run it.

```
typedef enum {MODE_A, MODE_B, MODE_C, MODE_D, MODE_E} mode_t;
long switch3 (long *p1, long *p2, mode_t action) {
    long result = 0;
    switch(action){
    case MODE_A:
    case MODE_B:
    case MODE_C:
    case MODE_D:
    case MODE_E:
    default:;    // don't forget the colon
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: First, fix the code. Then you can use `gcc -S` (not `-s`) to produce assembler.

Comment: I am planning to complete it before I compile it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Do I include the file name at the beginning when I compile it? Example: `filename.c gcc -s`

Comment: No, the file name follows the program name (it's a command line option). And a capital S, not a lower case one. `gcc -S filename.c` to produce assembler, `gcc filename.c` to produce an executable named `a.out` (the default) and `gcc filename.c -o filename` to produce an executable named `filename`. Assuming you only have one source file, and no external dependencies.

Comment: It would be `gcc -S filename.c`.  Options to GCC are case-sensitive; `-s` is an obsolete option for stripping the executable (it doesn't matter what that means; you don't use it any more anyway).  You need `-S` (capital S) to generate assembler code (`filename.s`).

Comment: The `-s` option tells the linker to strip symbols from the executable, which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open an editor, Vi or Emacs for example
2. Type and save your code in a file, maybe `main.c`
3. Exit the editor
4. Type `gcc -S main.c` or `clang -S main.c` in the terminal. You can also add a `-fverbose-asm` flag to tell the complier to add more information in the output, or a `-masm=intel` flag to inspect the assembly output much nicer.
5. On success, a file named `main.s` will be generated under the current directory, containing the assembly code; on failure, error messages will be printed on the screen.

Also note that your C code will only be compiled when it's **compilable**, so you have to modify your code first. At least, change `default;` to `default:;`

Here is the assembly code produced by `clang -S main.c` on my machine:

```
    .section    __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
    .macosx_version_min 10, 11
    .globl  _switch3
    .align  4, 0x90
_switch3:                               ## @switch3
    .cfi_startproc
## BB#0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp0:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp1:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp2:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
    movq    %rsi, -16(%rbp)
    movl    %edx, -20(%rbp)
    movq    $0, -32(%rbp)
    movl    -20(%rbp), %edx
    subl    $4, %edx
    movl    %edx, -36(%rbp)         ## 4-byte Spill
    ja  LBB0_2
    jmp LBB0_1
LBB0_1:
    jmp LBB0_2
LBB0_2:
    jmp LBB0_3
LBB0_3:
    movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
    popq    %rbp
    retq
    .cfi_endproc


.subsections_via_symbols
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for. So just this one line is enough to compile it? I remember compiling a file a while ago and I needed 4 steps to compile it with several switches. Like -o and -i

Comment: @Pauline Since you're only generating the assembly code, `gcc -S` or `clang -S` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

To compile without linking using GNU Compiler Collection (gcc) you can use the `-S` switch:

```
jan@jsn-dev:~/src/so> gcc -S main.c 
main.c: In function ‘switch3’:
main.c:11:12: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘;’ token
     default;
            ^
```

After correcting your code with the suggested fix, you get:

```
jan@jsn-dev:~/src/so> gcc -S main.c 
jan@jsn-dev:~/src/so> cat main.s 
        .file   "main.c"
        .text
        .globl  switch3
        .type   switch3, @function
switch3:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movq    %rdi, -24(%rbp)
        movq    %rsi, -32(%rbp)
        movl    %edx, -36(%rbp)
        movq    $0, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   switch3, .-switch3
        .ident  "GCC: (SUSE Linux) 4.8.3 20140627 [gcc-4_8-branch revision 212064]"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```